# Snackbar slide animation causes the floating action button to jump unexpectedly

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I have a floating action button in my activity. It should move up a little bit when a snackbar appears. but when I change my snackbar animation to slide using the code:

```
pressAgainToExitSnackBar.setAnimationMode(BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE);
```

The floating action button animation glitches for one frame or so. Like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using this version of google material design library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

Comment: Can you share your full `Snackbar` line

Comment: @PratikButani
`Snackbar pressAgainToExitSnackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_coordinator_layout), R.string.main_press_again_to_exit_snack_bar_text, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_SHORT);`
`pressAgainToExitSnackBar.setAnimationMode(BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE);`

Comment: I found this [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/603#issuecomment-532703894) and [Material Specs Behavior](https://material.io/components/snackbars/#behavior). I think it will not work as you want