# Snack bar slide animation causes the floating action button to jump unexpectedly

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I have a floating action button in my activity. It should move up a little bit when a snackbar appears. but when I change my snackbar animation to slide using the code:

```
pressAgainToExitSnackBar.setAnimationMode(BaseTransientBottomBar.ANIMATION_MODE_SLIDE);
```

The floating action button animation glitches for one frame or so. Like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using this version of google material design library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
```

PS2: I already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59468843/snackbar-slide-animation-causes-the-floating-action-button-to-jump-unexpectedly), but nobody seems to answer.