# Fab not being pushed up by snackbar above bottom Navigation

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

(this error is occuring in a big project, so i made a small one for easier demonstration)

I have been stuggling with this problem for a while now and i just cant find an answer anywhere

~Layout
[image: Layout without snackbar]

I want to push up the fab when a Snackbar is being displayed. When the bottom navigation bar is removed and i show a snackbar, the fab is being pushed up. But when i insert the bottom navigation bar, the snackbar appears, but the fab is not being pushed up

[image: Snackbar]

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            Snackbar
                .make(it, "tttt", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.bar))
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the name of `it` variable? I mean class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the bottom nav to another layout and wrapped the CoordinatorLayout inside linear layout, now the snack bar should take CoordinatorLayout as root and CoordinatorLayout will have the fab at the bottom, So it would lift it when snack comes.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/snackRoot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_circle" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_secondary"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

show snack bar

```
Snackbar
.make(activity.findViewById(R.id.snackRoot),
"tttt", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.show()
```

Comment: Thank you :) I don't know why i havent tried it but it works great

Comment: This causes the floating action button to jump unexpectedly. Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555532/snack-bar-slide-animation-causes-the-floating-action-button-to-jump-unexpectedly

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work around the issue successfully:

```
snackbar.addCallback(object : Snackbar.Callback() {
    override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?, event: Int) {
        transientBottomBar?.removeCallback(this)
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
            coordinatorLayout?.requestApplyInsets()
        }
    }
})
```